# Substring on pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, split

I want to extract a substring (Titles - Mr. Mrs, Miss etc.) from a column (Name) in a pandas dataframe and then  write the new column (Title) back into the dataframe.

In the Name column of the dataframe I have a name such as "Brand, Mr. Owen Harris"  The two delimiters are the , and .

I have attempted to use a split method, but  this only splits the original string in two within a list. So I still send up ['Braund', ' Mr. Owen Harris'] in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
#import re
df_Train = pd.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTliZmavBsJCFDiEwxcSIIftu-0gR9p34n8Bq4OUNL4TxwHY-JMS6KhZEbWr1bp91UqHPkliZBBFgwh/pub?gid=1593012114&single=true&output=csv')
a= df_Train['Name'].str.split(',')
for i in a:
    print(i[1])
```

I am thinking this might be situation where regex comes into play. My reading suggests a Lookahead (?=,)  and Lookbehind (?<='.') approach should do the trick. for example

```
import re
a= df_Train['Name'].str.split(r'(?=,)*(?<='.'))
for i in a:
    print(i)
    print(i[1])`
```

But I am running into errors (EOL while scanning string literal) .  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers
Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do it like this.

```
df_Train.Name.str.split(',').str[1].str.split('.').str[0].str.strip()
```

Output head(5):

```
0       Mr
1      Mrs
2     Miss
3      Mrs
4       Mr
```

Summation of results

```
df_Train.Name.str.split(',').str[1].str.split('.').str[0].str.strip()\
             .value_counts()
```

Output

```
Mr              517
Miss            182
Mrs             125
Master           40
Dr                7
Rev               6
Mlle              2
Col               2
Major             2
Lady              1
Mme               1
Sir               1
Ms                1
the Countess      1
Jonkheer          1
Don               1
Capt              1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what dataset are you using for this example?

Comment: Ok Great. I wasn't aware you could chain the methods like that.

Comment: ah missed that, just fyi you can just call `.value_counts()` on the resulting series rather than `.to_frame().groupby('Name')['Name'].count()`

Comment: I don't understand how exactly this works. What does the str[1] part do? Can someone explain?

Comment: @deadcode, the .str accessor is acting on a list and str[1] is retrieving the second element in the list created by split(',').  So in the case of  "Brand, Mr. Owen Harris", split(',') returns a list of two elements ["Brand", "Mr. Owen Harris"], then we use str[1] to get the second element "Mr. Owen Harris" and we split that string into ["Mr", "Owen Harris"[ using split('.') then use .str accessor again on the list to get the first element with .str[0].

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the fact that you have single quotes around the period inside your single-quoted regex string-literal; this actually isn't the correct syntax, I think you mean to use an escaped-period i.e. `r'(?=,)*(?<=\.)`. However you don't need to use lookahead/lookbehind here, it's more usual and simpler to use capture-groups to describe your regex; in this case the regex would be

```
df_Train['Name'].str.extract(", (\w*)\.")
```